# Multiple Config File for Flyway

Tags: flyway

Let say we have 10-15 micro services running and they have separate DB's. So how to maintain all these 15 config files at a single deployment server. As every db server has different creds, ip address and urls. So how will we manage all these in a single file or we'll have to create separate DB file per micro service ?

Answer (score 0):

Each configuration refers to a single database, so you need to create one file per DB for properties such as URL and credentials. Probably the best way to handle this is to have a repository of configurations named after their DBs, and your deployment mechanism uses the appropriate one. **However**, you can have a base configuration for common settings and just have connection details per database using the `configFiles` parameter, eg:

`flyway migrate -configFiles=/usr/configurations/base.conf,/usr/configurations/db1.conf`

will start from the base configuration and override any settings that also appear in the db1-specific configuration.